# What does the "ls -A" option do in linux?

Tags: linux

I was wondering what does the ls -A option do on it's own and why does it work in the code below when checking if a directory is empty or not... ?

I can't find any other answers online and the man pages I don't understand what it means when I read the documentation.

Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=""
DIR="/empty_dir"
# init
# look for empty dir 
if [ "$(ls -A $DIR)" ]; then
     echo "Take action $DIR is not Empty"
else
    echo "$DIR is Empty"
fi
# rest of the logic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing related to `bash`.  It tells `ls` to show all "hidden" files (those whose names start with `.`) except for `.` and `..` (special directory entries representing the current directory and the parent directory, respectively).

Compare with `ls -a`, which shows all hidden files including `.` and `..`. The presence of those two entries in the output would make the directory appear to be not empty, even though it really is.

Comment: I see. I think I get it now but would ls -a show . and .. to begin with ?
Also, I changed the title to linux sorry. I meant what is it's use in this bash script example but didn't explain myself properly